# Perl open file + hash + edit

Tags: perl, hash

I'm not getting the result expect from the following code:

```
#!/bash/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @file;
my $file2;

open (IN, "+</home/opmeitle/labs-perl/numbers");
@file = <IN>;
seek IN,0,0;

my %change = ( 80.928 => "85.950", 320.000  => "380.500");
my $changekey = join "|", keys %change;

foreach $file2 (@file){
$file2 =~ s/($changekey)/$change{$1}/g;
print IN $file2;}
close IN;
```

This is the contents of `/home/opmeitle/labs-perl/numbers`:

```
80.928
320.000
```

Here is the output:

```
85.950
380.500.000
```

Here is the result I desire:

```
85.950
380.500
```

I appreciate your answers.

luis.

but, looking this example, change in file numbers 80.928 and 320.000 for "Hola, mi nombre es Luis y vivo en Argentina" in code my %change = ( nombre => "name", mi => "my"); this is result "Hola, my name es Luis y vivo en Argentina a " in the end , an word the more! because?

Comment: hi, i'm needing, change in file, key for the values, hash

Comment: you need to paste some sample from '/home/opmeitle/labs-perl/numeros'

Comment: I understand, but you're reading the input file, performing some transformation, and then writing to the file.  So unless we know what the input looks like, we can't very well explain what your transform should be doing to get the desired output.  Edit your question by pasting the relevant input.

Comment: maybe your $file2 is 320.000.000, as that you may get the result 380.500.000

Comment: Also: You need to call [`truncate`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) in case the new file is smaller than the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is in `.` (dot)
`.` (dot) - in regular expression means "any symbol".

Your second problem in 320.000 -- this is the number and it's exactly equals to 320

320.000 =~ s/320/380.500/g; => 380.500.000

I suppose that solution may be in changing type of hash keys from numbers to strings
and escape all dots `'.' => '\.'`

To support my point of view, I wrote small script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %change = ( 80.928 => "85.950", 320.000  => "380.500");
my $changekey = join "|", keys %change;

print $changekey;
```

And voila, it produces output: `320|80.928`

But when %change hash is written as `my %change = ( "80.928" => "85.950", "320.000"  => "380.500");`, output would be `320.000|80.928`

And the third problem, you open file in read-write mode, but when resulting file has less size then source, at the end would be rubbish. To avoid this, you must use `truncate`, or open file in readonly mode, read it, close, and after that open it in writeonly mode.

Comment: but, looking this example, change in file numbers 80.928 and 320.000 for "Hola, mi nombre es Luis y vivo en Argentina" in code my %change = ( nombre => "name", mi  => "my"); this is result "Hola, my name es Luis y vivo en Argentina
a
" in the end , an word the more! because?

Comment: How about this: '320.000' =~ s/320.000/380.500/g;

Comment: helped me, thanks! but remember this code modified;  change in file numbers 80.928 and 320.000 for "Hola, mi nombre es Luis y vivo en Argentina" in code my %change = ( nombre => "name", mi => "my"); this is result "Hola, my name es Luis y vivo en Argentina a " in the end , an word the more!

Comment: As @CyberDem0n (and ikegami in a comment) mentioned, `truncate` is also useful here.  But frankly, I seldom find it useful to open a file in '`+<`' mode.  It just adds unneeded complexity.  Your solution could read one file line by line, process that line, output it to a different file, and in the end, pull a switcheroo with the filenames.  No need for `seek`, no `truncate`, no writing to the same file you're trying to read, no worrying about whether any of the lines consumes more (or less) bytes after being altered than the original.  KISS should stand for "Keeping It Simple is Smarter".

Comment: I appreciate your answers and  understanding my words, I don't very well in english.